# How to pass value from activity to Tab Fragment using replace Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have activity , which I take a value from it and pass it to Tab Fragment
.. in the Tab Fragment ,I want to use this value to setText

**The Problem is** How to take this value to the Tab Fragment ? 
I always get this Exception   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id ....for fragment Tab1 .. How to solve it ?

I used normal Tab activity in android studio and modified this method

homee.java

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 =new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 =new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 =new Tab3();
                return tab3;
        }
        return null ;
    }
```

this is my activity number.java

```
public class number extends AppCompatActivity {
Button add,save;
TextView num;
int n;
String stringNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);

    add =  findViewById(R.id.idadd);
    save =  findViewById(R.id.idsave);
    num = findViewById(R.id.idnum);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //simple method
            n = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
            num.setText(++n +"");
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringNum= num.getText().toString(); 
// I want to pass this value to Tab1 Fragment by replaceFragment or by any 
//way
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", stringNum);
            Tab1 myFragment = new Tab1();
            myFragment.setArguments(bundle);


     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
     (R.id.container,myFragment).commit();
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

this is Tab1 child of Tab activity

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

Button get,update;
TextView txt;

public Tab1(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    get = view.findViewById(R.id.idget);
    update = view.findViewById(R.id.idup);
    txt = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getContext(), number.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Number= getArguments().getString("key").toString();
            //here the problem
            txt.setText(Number);
        }
    });

        return view;
        }
    }
```

activity_homee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="eg.noname.opo.homee">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

tab1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fra">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="get" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/idup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="update" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** I solved it by call static method which return this value , but still I should press on Button in Fragment to update the value to the new one , I am trying to find a way to update the value automatically when I pass it from my  activity .. any help ?

Comment: can you explain first two line of question. What you want to ask?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Ok I edited it .. is it clear now ?

Comment: Debug this line **`stringNum= num.getText().toString(); `**  and check hear u r getting a value or not..?

Answer (score 0):

in activity number.java

```
  in onCreate method just call
  String Number= getArguments().getString("key").toString();
        //here the problem
        txt.setText(Number)
```

Comment: but i still can't receive the value "Number" by Bundle .. I always get this Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id ....for fragment Tab1

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass value while calling Fragment in getItem() method.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
              Tab1 tab1= new Tab1();
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.putString("name", name);
              tab1.setArguments(bundle);
              return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2= new Tab2();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("mobile", mobile);
            tab2.setArguments(bundle);
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3= new Tab3();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("email", email);
            tab3.setArguments(bundle);
            return tab3;
    }
    return null ;
}
```

You can check it in next fragments simply by:

```
if( getArguments() != null) {
        name = getArguments().getString("name");
```

Hope this helps u.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass following bundle with your fragment which one you want to pass data :

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();//create bundle instance
data.putString("key_value", "String to pass");//put string to pass with key 
fragmentName.setArguments(data);//Set bundle data to fragment
```

You can retrieve data with following code in next fragment :

```
 String getArgument = getArguments().getString("data");
 text.setText(getArgument); //set string over textview
```

Comment: Because in FragmentAdapter it Makes New Object of Second TAB Fragment Which has no passed Values... In case of Normal Fragment this answer is correct..